# How do I convert this line of VBA into LibreOffice Basic?

Tags: excel, vba, libreoffice, basic

How do I convert the VBA

```
 With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A1:A10").Copy
        .Range("D1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
```

to LibreOffice Basic with Option VBASupport 1

I thought this would work but PasteSpecial is not working the same way as it does in Excel and I can't see any pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code it like this

```
With ThisComponent.getSheets().getByName("Sheet1")
    .getCellRangeByName("D1:D10").setDataArray(.getCellRangeByName("A1:A10").getDataArray())
End With
```

Comment: Thank you @JohnSUN!